# Why do I have, and how to prevent, duplicate items in DropDownButton items?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I'm creating a simple interface for user to select a client from a dropdown. However I end up with duplications of values in the menu items. How do I prevent this? (and why is it happening?)

The list of clients is a singleton that might be populated or empty - and my intention is to add a search field and - and this 'listicle' is shared amongst various routes.

I'm relatively new to Flutter/Dart & OOP.

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

import 'package:agent_01/presentation/state/entity_types/client_listicle.dart';
import 'package:agent_01/presentation/state/entity_types/message_listicle_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

class MessageEditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessageEditPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = "/messages/edit";

  @override
  State<MessageEditPage> createState() => _MessageEditPageState();
}

class _MessageEditPageState extends State<MessageEditPage> {
  late MessageLItem? messageLI;
  late bool haveDetail;
  late ClientListicle clientListicle = GetIt.I.get<ClientListicle>();
  final msgEdtFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String dropdownValue = "";
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
    const DropdownMenuItem(value: "", child: Text('Select')),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    developer.log('initState', name: '_MessagePageState');
    if (dropdownValue.isEmpty) {
      developer.log('set to 1st ', name: '_MessagePageState');
      dropdownValue = dropdownItems.first.value!;
    }
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems {
    developer.log('have  ${clientListicle.items.length} clients',
        name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
    developer.log('have  ${menuItems.length} menuItems',
        name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
    if (clientListicle.items.isEmpty) {
      developer.log('go fetch', name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
      fetchClients();
    }
    developer.log('menuItems ${menuItems.toString()}', name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
    for (var element in clientListicle.items) {
      developer.log('el ${element.toString()}', name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
      DropdownMenuItem<String> potentialItem =
          DropdownMenuItem(value: element.id.toString(), child: Text(element.title));
      if (!menuItems.contains(potentialItem)) {
        developer.log('dont have so add', name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
        menuItems.add(potentialItem);
      } else {
        developer.log('skip', name: '_MessagePageState get dropdownItems');
      }
    }
    return menuItems;
  }

  Future<void> fetchClients() async {
    await clientListicle.fetch(numberToFetch: 5);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    developer.log('have CL ${clientListicle.items.length}', name: '_MessagePageState build');

    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Row(children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 12,
                height: 1,
              ),
              RichText(
                text: const TextSpan(
                  text: 'Write new message...', //messageLI.title,
                  // style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                ),
                maxLines: 3,
              )
            ])),
            body: Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Form(
                  key: msgEdtFormKey,
                  child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
                    DropdownButton(
                      // Initial Value
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      // Down Arrow Icon
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                      items: dropdownItems,
                      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                        developer.log('click $newValue', name: '_MessagePageState');
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = newValue!;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    const TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      minLines: 1, //Normal textInputField will be displayed
                      maxLines: 5, // when user presses enter it will adapt to it
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        developer.log('Send', name: '_MessagePageState');
                      },
                      child: Text('Send'),
                    )
                  ])),
            ))));
  }
}

/*
class ScreenArguments {
  final MessageLItem? message;
  ClientLItem? clientLItem;

  ScreenArguments(this.message, this.clientLItem);
}*/
```

and log output for this if accessing the screen with 3 items allready in the clients listicle:

```
[_MessagePageState] initState
[_MessagePageState] set to 1st 
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] have  3 clients
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] have  1 menuItems
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] menuItems [DropdownMenuItem<String>]
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
[_MessagePageState build] have CL 3
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] have  3 clients
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] have  4 menuItems
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] menuItems [DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>, DropdownMenuItem<String>]
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] el Instance of 'ClientLItem'
[_MessagePageState get dropdownItems] dont have so add
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: I'm not sure about the `get dropdownItems` - obviously that get's called on rebuild. The main issue though seems to be that `if (!menuItems.contains(potentialItem))` doesn't work. So, I've replaced that with below which seems to solve the imediate problem but seems hacky:

```
 for (var element in clientListicle.items) {
      DropdownMenuItem<String> potentialItem =
          DropdownMenuItem(value: element.id.toString(), child: Text(element.title));
      bool isHave = false;
      for (var exstElement in menuItems) {
        if (exstElement.value == element.id.toString()) {
          isHave = true;
        }
      }
      if (!isHave) {
        menuItems.add(potentialItem);
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
    return menuItems;
```

Should I be defining a whole new class for the dropDowmMenuItems?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Set, it will have unique value,

```dart
 for (var element in clientListicle.items.toSet().toList()) {
      developer.log('el ${element.toString()}',
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ok try update one. Make set just after you get the strings

Comment: Neither. An old-school loop test seems to work 
```
for (var element in clientListicle.items) {
      DropdownMenuItem<String> potentialItem =
          DropdownMenuItem(value: element.id.toString(), child: Text(element.title));
      bool isHave = false;
      for (var exstElement in menuItems) {
        if (exstElement.value == element.id.toString()) {
          isHave = true;
        }
      }
      if (!isHave) {
        menuItems.add(potentialItem);
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
    return menuItems;
```

Comment: I thought element itself a string -/.  you can map and convert them on single line

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/lodash_flutter

maybe, you can check this package it's helpful for you.

> "uniq" method will work for you.

Example,

```
List myList = [{"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'}]
   print(LodashFlutter.uniq(myList));
```

---

```
//Results
[{"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
   {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'}]
```